# WordPress: Import MySQL database to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to import a MySQL dump (export from phpMyAdmin) on a new server with phpMyAdmin. The new server runs on MariaDB and the import skips everytime with an error message.

- The MySQL version is: 5.5.52-log
- The MariaDB version is: 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~trusty

The error message is #1064. From the docs:

```
Error: 1064 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_PARSE_ERROR)
Message: %s near '%s' at line %d
```

There are also a lot of notices about "Uninitialized string offsets".

Any ideas?

First 20 lines:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: show top 20 lines of your file. Which MySQL Version you have use to create the dump

Comment: see lines above

Comment: Let's see the 1064 from running the code, not from the docs.

Comment: I could solve it, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by deleting the comments and the following line:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Thanks Bernd Buffen for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

It a little work. Remove all BAckticks in the Comments like this:

**from**

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `yourTable` 
--
```

**to**

```
--
-- Dumping data for table yourTable 
--
```

or remove the lines

Comment: Is it only this? Is there a way to remove these lines on the export?

Comment: linux? use this : **$ grep -v "^--- " orgdump.sql >newdump.sql** will remove all lines starting with "--- "

Comment: I exported without comments but the errors are still there

Comment: can you refresh the top lines of your dumpfile.

Comment: this looks god and also works on my server. if there are no secrets in it you can zip it and send it me by email and i will fix it for you

Comment: I really appreciate your offer but unfortunately it's a client DB :( What would you do to fix it?

Comment: 1) i take a look in it; i import it on MariaDB Server; when there are errors i split it into table files (create and insert) pieces and test each to find which generate the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138245/discussion-between-cray-and-bernd-buffen).